# Match same string twice within certain characters

Tags: regex

I need to write a regex that matches patterns like this:

```
[[string|string]]
```

It's the same string twice within that specific syntax (I don't want to match the brackets themselves). I managed to come up with this:

```
(?<=\[\[)(.*)(?=\|)\|\1\]\]
```

However, it's not matching for some reason and I don't understand where's my mistake.

UPDATE: Turns out it wasn't working because my code was dirty and there were some ● characters in the first string, so both strings weren't equal: https://regexr.com/3n7ni

Removing those extraneous characters made the regex match, although it still needed tweaks (like not matching the closure brackets): https://regexr.com/3n7o7

Comment: "doesn't work" meaning what exactly? That regex _works_. If it doesn't, the problem is your code.

Comment: @Aran-Fey No matches found: https://regexr.com/3n7ni

Comment: Try [`\[{2}([^|\]]+)\|\1]{2}`](https://regex101.com/r/V7ubiK/1). Also, which language?

Comment: Have you noticed the big red "ERROR: lookbehind not supported in this flavor" message? If you test it somewhere where it's actually supported, it works.

Comment: @Aran-Fey: Found the error, there were some weird  ● characters in my code, ugh. This does match: https://regexr.com/3n7o7

Comment: @Stealth did you try my regex yet? You haven't answered which language. regexr is JavaScript-based and so it doesn't support lookbehinds. You need to give us which regex engine/flavour/language you're using.

Comment: @ctwheels Sorry, I was just testing your code. It does work fantastically. I'm not sure about the language since it's for a regex software (although seems to be written in C#). In any case, your code is what I wanted. If you post it as answer I can choose it as the accepted one unless someone submits something better. :)

Comment: @Stealth done :)

Comment: @ctwheels I don't think it's valid to say that the question is about rewriting the regex without a lookbehind just because the online regex tester was incorrectly set to javascript. If the question _is_ about making that regex work without a lookbehind, then that should be explicitly stated in the question and not implied by posting a link to a regex tester that shows an error message. If you want to edit the question into shape, go ahead. But until someone does that, my close vote stays.

Comment: I've edited my question with some rewoding. When I said "it doesn't work" I  meant simply that it wasn't working whatsoever, no matches at all. Fortunately @ctwheels understood the problem clearly and provided me the code I was looking for, and so I've chosen their answer as the accepted one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/V7ubiK/1)

```
\[{2}([^|\]]+)\|\1]{2}
```

- `\[{2}` Matches `[` literally, twice
- `([^|\]]+)` Captures one or more of any character except `|` or `]` into capture group 1
- `\|` Matches `|` literally
- `\1` Matches the text most recently captured into capture group 1
- `]{2}` Matches `]` literally, twice

Answer (score 1):

To match the full pattern you can update your regex to include the first 2 brackets:

[`\[\[(.*)\|\1\]\]`](https://regex101.com/r/xWG03K/1)

I think you could also do without this positive lookahead `(?=\|)`.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't match what OP wants to match. OP wants the square brackets included in the match, but your regex only matches `string|string`

Comment: This may give unexpected results: `[[s|s]]|s|s]]]]`. Then again, it could also be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the use of a greedy match `(.*)` (consume as much as possible). You should be using a *reluctant* match `(.*?)` (consume as little as possible):

```
\[\[(.*?)\|\1\]\]
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/yOfGJxbmXY).

Note that your look ahead `(?=\|)` is useless.

Comment: This can actually fail hard given an unusually structured string: `[[s|string]]|s|string]]]]`

Comment: @ctwheels I can live with that. I am willing to bet big bucks such input will never happen for OP. I favor readability.

Comment: I completely agree, but I just thought it should be presented as a possible case. We don't really *know* what the OP is dealing with in terms of strings, so it's possible that a very unlikely string (such as that one) shows up and stumps them. (Maybe it's user input, someone can try to break it).

Comment: I don't see what difference changing `.*` to `.*?` makes. The regex will backtrack until it finds the correct match anyway.

Comment: @Aran-Fey try it against the input `[[s|s]]|s|s]]]]`

Comment: @ctwheels Well, that's ambiguous. The OP never stated what the expected result is in that case. The OP simply stated that the regex "doesn't work" without explaining what it's supposed to do with ambiguous input like that or showing proof that it really doesn't work (and it turned out to work just fine). I don't see why this question isn't closed as "lacks MCVE" yet, and why everyone keeps posting different ways to write the "same" (more or less) regex.

Comment: @Aran-Fey because the issue is the lookbehind. The OP shared a link that shows it giving an error due to the usage of lookbehind. While the question itself doesn't give any indication of what is not properly working, the OP did provide a link to the issue in the comments below it. In any case, I think we should clean up our comments below Bohemian's answer because this discussion is better intended for extended discussion (or chat). It's not fair to Bohemian to continue to post comments on his answer. If you have an issue with the question post a comment below it and let the OP know.